# Differences between Vector magnitude and distance vector

Tags: vectors, normed-spaces

I will be so grateful if someone can explain me in a simple language what is difference between vector magnitude namely $$r=\left|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2\right|$$ and distance vector namely $$\vec r_{12}=\vec r_1-\vec r_2$$ or introduce a good reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take an example in the plane. Let $\vec{a} = (1,0)$ and $\vec{b} = (0,1)$. Then the difference vector is $$\vec{r}_{ab} = \vec{b} - \vec{a} = (0,1) - (1,0) = (-1,1).$$ In other words, if you are walking from $a$ and want to go to $b$, you need to make one step to the left and another step up.

Finally, note that
$$
r = \left|\vec{r}_{ab}\right| = \sqrt{(-1)^2 + 1^2} = \sqrt2,
$$
so if you are walking from $a$ to $b$ directly, on a straight line segment, you will have to walk a grand total of $\sqrt2$ units.

Answer (score 1):

Your $r$ is the **length of the distance** from two points indicated by the vectors $r_1$ and $r_2$.

$\vec r_{12}$ is a **vector**, this means that it is not only the length of the distance from two points but also the **orientation** of this distance, **directed** from $r_1$ to $r_2$